# Get hours and minutes from std::string boost c++

Tags: c++, boost

I want to get only hours and minutes from std::string date time in boost C++.
I have below code.

```
std::string d_time = std::string("2017-09-25 12:23:10");
```

I can get it by tokenizing the above string but is there any standard boost function that will give only hours and minutes from "d_time" ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Some systems have a function called `strptime` that can convert a time and date string into a `struct tm`, from which you can get the information you want. You could check that.

Comment: You could also use [`std::get_time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time) in conjunction with an [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream).

Comment: But struct tm will not be available in windows right ?

Comment: If you have functions in the `std` namespace, you can be certain that it is coming from the standard, and that any standard-compliant compiler must implement it, in full. Including structures like [`std::tm`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/tm). Platform does not matter (and remember that `struct tm` is an old structure originally from the C standard and has existed on all platforms, including Windows, for ages).

Comment: "std::get_time" and "std::put_time" is not supported in gcc < 5.x so that can not be used.

Comment: GCC version 4 have never claimed to be fully C++11 compliant. And nowhere in your question have you mentioned that you need pre-C++11 support.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude [C++11 Support in GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx11) _"GCC 4.8.1 was the first feature-complete implementation of the 2011 C++ standard, previously known as C++0x.

This mode can be selected with the -std=c++11 command-line flag, or -std=gnu++11 to enable GNU extensions as well._" So there's that. Note too that std::regex support wasn't complete until much later, I think, even though the interface was there before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions [`std::get_time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time) and [`std::put_time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time) can help you with that.

Such functions operate with `stream` objects, so you can use a `stringstream` if you want to handle strings.

```
std::istringstream time_stream{d_time};  // Construct a stream from string
std::tm time;  // Time structure
time_stream >> std::get_time(&time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");  // Fill time struct
```

Once you have proper initialized `std::tm` structure, you can extract the needed information (hours and minutes).

[Here](https://ideone.com/3Ca567) a live demo.

Note that such functions are part of the *standard* C++11.

Comment: Note also that [gcc 4.x](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vEYlLpND6ANIlSk7) didn't implement it even in C++11 mode. You need at least 5.x

Comment: Here, what about if we use older version of gcc < 5 where "std::get_time" and "std::put_time" is not supported ?

Comment: using g++8.3 on debian 10 and std::get_time is not properly implemented: doesn't allow for single digit day of month without preceding 0.... so the boost solution below is definitely preferred.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a version of compiler/standard libraries that doesn't properly implement the put_time/get_time manipulators, here's a small piece of code using Boost DateTime

**<kbd>[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Q1Vd5C6fUA5NexYu)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

using boost::posix_time::time_from_string;

int main() {
    auto time = time_from_string("2017-09-25 12:23:10").time_of_day();;

    int hours = time.hours();
    int minutes = time.minutes();

    std::cout << "hours: " << hours << " minutes:" << minutes << "\n";
}
```

Comment: It gives compilation error saying "class boost::posix_time::ptime’ has no member named ‘hours’"

Comment: There's a live demo. Watch closely (you forgot the `time_of_day()` call)